# Can I choose a random element from a set if I don't know the size of the set?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, graph-theory

I'm writing a bit of JavaScript code which should select a random item from a canvas if the item meets certain requirements. There are different kinds of items (circles, triangles, squares etc.) and there's usually not the same number of items for each kind. The items are arranged in a hierarchy (so a square can contain a few circles, and a circle can contain other circles and so on - they can all be nested).

Right now, my (primitive) approach at selecting a random item is to:

1. Recursively traverse the canvas and build a (possibly huge!) list of items
2. Shuffle the list
3. Iterate the shuffled list from the front until I find an item which meets some extra requirements.

The problem with this is that it doesn't scale well. I often run into memory issues because either the recursion depth is too high or the total list of items becomes too large.

I was considering to rewrite this code so that I consider choosing elements as I traverse the canvas - but I don't know how I could "randomly" choose an element if I don't know how many elements there are in total.

Does anybody have some idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want "true" randomness, or "random enough" elements ?

Comment: Nope. And if you do manage then you should know the size of the set by the end :)

Comment: @Alexandre: It just needs to be random enough really - I don't need a perfect distribution.

Comment: @Frerich: So @Botz3000 's answer is good enough

Comment: @Alexandre C. Why create a list when you don't have to?

Comment: @Andreas: Only keep the idea of selecting a branch at random.

Comment: What everybody is describing is called reservoir sampling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling (the wikipedia article is not very good though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with `max_r = -1` and `rand_node = null`. Iterate through the tree. For each node meeting the criteria:

```
r = random()
if r > max_r:
  rand_node = node
  max_r = r
```

At the end `rand_node` will be a randomly selected node with only a single iteration required.

Comment: Is this code guaranteed to give an uniform distribution? My intuition says it will but I'm having trouble analysing it, since the algorithm is carrying over state from the previous iteration.

Comment: @Andreas It's equivalent to randomly mapping N distinct values (chance of collisions is minimal) to N elements, and then picking the largest one. Perhaps that makes it easier to see it?

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent explanation! But what if several elements map to the same (pseudo) random value, does that affect the distribution?

Comment: @Andreas It will affect it by choosing the element that comes first, but the chance of such a collision is so minimal that a good RNG is far more important.

Comment: +1: I like how short this solution is. It works good enough for my cases.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without first creating a list (sorry for my C pseudo code)

```
int index = 0;
foreach (element)
{
    if (element matches criteria)
    {
        index++;
        int rand = random value in [1 index] range
        if (1 == rand)
        {
            chosen = element;
        }
    }
}
```

The math works out, say you have a list where 3 of the elements match the criteria, the probability that the first element will be chosen is:

```
1 * (1 - 1 / 2) * (1 - 1 / 3) = 1 * (1 / 2) * (2 / 3) = 1 / 3
```

The probability of the second being chose is:

```
(1 / 2) * (1 - 1 / 3) = (1 / 2) * (2 / 3) = 1 / 3
```

and finally for the third element

```
1 / 3
```

Which is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm probably misreading your pseudo-code, but wouldn't this always select the first element matching the criteria? On the first matching element, `index` becomes `1` so `rand` becomes `random value in [1 1] range` - which would be `1`, no?

Comment: Yes, but you continue iterating afterwards, which means that `chosen` can be replaced by another element. See the probability analysis. marcog's answer might be correct as well, but it's not as easy to analyze.

Comment: Ah, I see! Very nice answer - I can see how (and why!) this works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively do this:

1. Traverse the current tree level, creating a list
2. Select a random node from it (using a random number from 0 to list.Length)
3. Repeat until you get to a leaf node

that would give items in small subtrees a higher probability of being selected though.

Alternatively, you don't need to build a list, you only need to keep track of the number of items. That would mean traversing the tree a second time to get to the selected item, but you wouldn't need the extra memory for the list.