# How to choose an element of a stream of unknown size uniformly at random?

Tags: algorithm

I had the following question a couple weeks ago in an interview and haven't been able to figure it out.

"Given a stream of numbers that is too large to fit into memory. Return a number in the stream at random. The only methods you can use on the stream is a boolean hasNext() and int getNext().  The range of numbers is type long"

Comment: Do you know the length of the stream beforehand?

Comment: Was it for any particular environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I choose a random element from a set if I don't know the size of the set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679744/can-i-choose-a-random-element-from-a-set-if-i-dont-know-the-size-of-the-set)

Comment: No we don't know the length of the stream. Not for any particular environment, interviewer said I can code in whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem constraints, it is reasonable to assume that the
algorithm is going to look like this:

```
// Returns a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1
double rand();

// Some unknown function that we are looking for
double f(long);

long choose() {
    long cur = 0;   // Number that we've chosen so far
    long pos = 0    // Just tracks the position where we picked
                    // cur, not actually used
    long count = 0; // Number of the current iteration
    while (hasNext()) {
        int next = getNext();
        if (rand() < f(count)) {
            cur = next;
            pos = count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

Thus, the question becomes: how do we implement `f` to get a uniform
distribution? It is clear that, after executing `count` iterations,
the variable `pos` should be a uniformly distributed number between
`0` and `count - 1`. I.e.,

```
prob(pos, count) = (pos <= count - 1) ? 1 / count : 0
```

For if `hasNext()` returns `false` on the next iteration, we want to
guarantee that `cur` will have the desired distribution. On the other
hand, if `hasNext()` returns `true` and our invariant holds, the
probability that we will pick the next element will be
`f(count)`. Thus, if we want to maintain our invariant by the end of
the iteration, we should do

```
double f(long count) {
    return 1 / (double) (count + 1);
}
```

We would then need to ensure that this would readjust the probability
for all elements that came before in a correct manner. But this is
clear, because of our invariant

```
prob(pos, count+1) = (pos == count) ? f(count) :
                                      (1 - f(count)) * prob(pos, count)
                   = (pos == count) ? f(count) :
                     (pos <  count) ? (1 - f(count)) * 1 / count : 0
                   = (pos == count) ? f(count) :
                     (pos <  count) ? count / (count + 1) / count : 0
                   = (pos == count) ? f(count) :
                     (pos <  count) ? f(count) : 0
                   = (pos <= count + 1 - 1) ? f(count) : 0
```